# How can I pick block on a touchscreen?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I'm trying to pick a block on Minecraft Education Edition for iPad, but I can't.

I've tried changing the settings, but as the game is on an iPad, and the settings are for a keyboard, it seems impossible to assign something that would work in this case.

Comment: Allegedly, tapping with two fingers at once simulates middle-click on iPad. You might try this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, it doesn't seem possible (without mods).

The "pick block" function is normally bound to the "mouse3" button, and while it is a configurable control, on the iPad, you're limited to simply tapping on the screen. If at all, the only function I can think of is a "tap" or a "long tap" (i.e. hold your finger on the screen for longer than 1 second). *If* that is a function, I daresay that it is already bound to something else (e.g. digging).

Comment: Tap is place block/interact with block/punch, long tap is break block/interact with entity